# parsing log4j log file using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, log4j

I have created a java application for parsing the log4j log file using regular expression, The application is working fine for the log which i have shown below

```
1999-11-27 15:49:37,459 [thread-x] ERROR mypackage - Catastrophic system failure
```

but not working for

```
2015-01-22 01:52:54,237 [http-bio-80-exec-5] FATAL   TestLog4jServlet - Show FATAL message
```

My log4j ConversionPattern is given below

```
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-7p %10c{1} - %m%n
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My code is as given below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2},\\d{3}) \\[(.*)\\] ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) - (.*)$";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    String[] samples = {
            "2015-01-22 01:52:54,237 [http-bio-80-exec-5] FATAL   TestLog4jServlet - Show FATAL message"
        };

    Matcher m = p.matcher(samples[1]);
    System.out.println(m.matches());
    if (m.matches() && m.groupCount() == 6) {
        String date = m.group(1);
        String time = m.group(2);
        String threadId = m.group(3);
        String priority = m.group(4);
        String category = m.group(5);
        String message = m.group(6);

        System.out.println("date: " + date);
        System.out.println("time: " + time);
        System.out.println("threadId: " + threadId);
        System.out.println("priority: " + priority);
        System.out.println("category: " + category);
        System.out.println("message: " + message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are two spaces between `FATAL`   and `TestLog4jServlet` but you included only one space in your regex. So i suggest you to replace the corresponding space with `<space>+` which allows one or more spaces.

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) \[(.*?)\] ([^ ]*) +([^ ]*) - (.*)$
                                                                ^
                                                                |
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aQ7yS5/5)

Java regex would be,

```
"(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2},\\d{3}) \\[(.*)\\] ([^ ]*) +([^ ]*) - (.*)$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Logstash is better for parsing log.

Comment: Create a conf file like logstash.conf with the content below : `input {
 file {
  path => "/your/log/absolupath"
 }
}

filter {
 grok {
  match => [ "message","%{DATA:date} \[%{DATA:threadId}\]\s+%{DATA:priority}\s+%{DATA:category}\s+-\s+%{GREEDYDATA:message}"  ]
 }
 date {
        match => [ "date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    }
}

output {
 file {
  path => "/your/output/absolupath"
 }
}` And then run the logstash : `./logstash agent -f logstash.conf`, you can find in your output file a json data for the parsed log.

Comment: @Alex I think Zheng is saying: "don't try to parse it yourself.  Set up and use Logstash to parse your log files".  You might want it if you are centralising your logs / making them searchable, not sure what your use case is.  Note: it's not answering your question directly

Answer (score 0):

added group names to the detected regex patterns
[Regex for parsing log4j log](https://regex101.com/r/DYYIVS/1)

```
(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) +(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) +(\[thread-(?<threadId>.*?)\])(?<logLevel>\S*) (?<package>(.*?)) - (?<msg>.*)
```